# How to specify the number of cores from the linux command line?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I have a MATLAB script using parallel `for` loops.  I want to run my script on a Linux server but I don't know how can I run it from the linux shell without displaying the MATLAB GUI.  Also, how can I specify number of cores to use?

Comment: Does `matlab --nodesktop` do what you want? See: http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2010/02/22/launching-matlab-without-the-desktop/

Comment: How can specify number of cores?

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

1. `matlab -nodesktop`
2. Use [`maxNumCompThreads`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/maxnumcompthreads.html) to set the total number of threads / cores for MATLAB to use.

If you require MATLAB to run on a single thread, use `matlab -singleCompThread`.  However, I'm not sure why you'd want to control the total number of cores.  By default, MATLAB makes use of the multithreading capabilities of the machine it's running on.

As an additional sidenote, `maxNumCompThreads` will be removed in future releases of MATLAB, so don't rely on this behaviour if you desire longetivity.